# How do we run automated testing when using OAuth2 and Azure AD

Tags: azure, api, oauth-2.0, active-directory, jwt

Our scenario is that we have an API which is currently only secured by a subscription key in APIM.

We plan to change this to also secure it with OAuth 2 following this [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) from Microsoft, we will then use the JWT validation policies within APIM to ensure that the user requesting access is a member of the appropriate groups to access given endpoints etc.

However as part of our release process we need to run some automated tests which call the API and check that certain data is returned.

Because these tests are run as part of an automated release pipeline we are struggling to understand how OAuth will fit into this process - as a user is required to enter credentials for a token to be issued...

We originally thought that we could just request a token manually once and then hard code it into the tests, but as tokens are only valid for a short time this isn't a good solution.

Other things we are considering are :

- Creating a "test user" in AD and storing their credentials in the test project and then when the tests run we can request a token using the "Password" grant type and passing the username and password" however this doesn't seem like the best from a security point of view, even though the user would only have access to a very limited subset of the APIs functionality it still doesn't seem like a good practice.
- Requesting a token using the client secret, however the downside to that is this is that the JWT does not contain the `groups` claim so this token will not pass JWT Validation.

This must be something that others have encountered? What is best practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that we went with in the end was to create a new App Registration for the Test project, then in APIM we added a rule so that the JWT policy is not applied to connections from that app.

Might not be the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the article you reference, you will be using Azure API Management to be the entry point to access your API. So, using the API Management you will have subscriptions with keys for your API. You just need to create a subscription for your automated testing, and save the key in the Azure Key Vault. And then during the deployment, you pull your subscription key from your Key Vault, and use it to call the API Management Endpoint, that consequently will call your API.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear. We are using OAuth and JWT Validation within APIM. So we need the Authorization header with the JWT to be present when we call APIM, we already use a subscription key but this is not granular enough as we will be using AD groups (and JWT validation) to restrict access to certain endpoints within the API. Ill edit the question to make this clearer.